# Selectively reading string part of a file using C

Tags: c, file-handling

I have a .txt file with strings each line and a number assigned to each string and a `-` in between the string and the number.

[image: String file]

Now I want to read only the string part not the number or the `-` in between, store them in an array and write only the strings in another file.

I used the following approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 100

struct String {
    long long int num;
    char name[50];
    char C;
} S[MAX], temp;

void file_write(int n, struct String S[]) {
    FILE *pp;
    pp = fopen("std3.txt", "a");       //second file where I want to write only string part.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fprintf(pp, "%s", S[i].name);    //storing the strings in another file
        fputs("\n", pp);
    }
    fclose(pp);
}

int main() {
    int n;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("str.txt", "r");
    printf("Enter the number of strings : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fscanf(fp, " %[^\n]", S[i].name);
        fscanf(fp, "%lld", &S[i].num);
        fscanf(fp, "%c", &S[i].C);
    }
    file_write(n, S);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

But I'm getting an undesirable output:

[image]

Comment: Please replace the images with equivalent text.

Comment: use [fgets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) and [strtok](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html)

Comment: All the lines follow this pattern? You want to grab the first thing that is a letter until the end of the line?

Comment: I want the string part from each line for example - EFGH KL from first line, then CDD KJN from the second line and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using `fscanf()` and the `*` assignment suppression option:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen("str.txt", "r");
    // second file where I want to write only string part.
    FILE *pp = fopen("std3.txt", "a");
    if (fp == NULL || pp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open files\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Enter the number of strings: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char name[50];
        int c;
        if (fscanf(fp, "%*d - %49[^\n]", name) == 1) {
            fprintf(pp, "%s\n", name);
            /* flush any extra characters and the newline if present */
            while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n')
                continue;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(pp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this way but I'm getting an error stating:-                                                          
name.c: In function ‘main’:
name.c:32:19: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘scanf’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   32 |         if (scanf(fp, "%*d - %[^\n]%*c",S[i].name)!= 1)
      |                   ^~
      |                   |
      |                   FILE * {aka struct _IO_FILE *}

Comment: @NovaStark: sorry about that, answer updated.

Comment: thanks a ton buddy, that was really helpful. Just a small question can you please explain what exactly %*d - %49[^\n] does?

Comment: @NovaStark: `%*d` parses an integer but does not store it, hence it does not take a pointer to `int`, `%49[\n]` stores up to 49 characters into the array passed as an argument stopping at the newline or end of file. The newline is left pending in the stream. The next call to `getc()` will return either the 50th character in the line or the newline depending if more than 49 characters were present after `-` before  the end of line.

Answer (score 0):

Scanf (and its variations) is a very powerful function... I think the following line is what you want.

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    fscanf(fp, "%*[^A-Z]%[^\n]", S[i].name);
}
```

A brief description of what it does is: It discards any character that is not a capital letter then reads everything from the first capital letter until the end of line.

If the names are allowed to start with lowercase, you can change it to:

```
 fscanf(fp, "%*[^A-Za-z]%[^\n]", S[i].name);
```

Comment: You should check the return value to detect invalid or non conforming input.

Comment: Actually here I've placed a sample text file where all strings are in capital letter but my original text file contains names of people with both capital and small letters where from I want to extract only the name part, so I want a generalised solution.

Comment: Explain the pattern... Is it a sequence of numbers, then a minus then what really matters? Do you want to catch everything after the minus sign? And ignore the minus sign and everything before it?

Comment: This solution works for that, it only assumes the name starts with a capital letter. Do you have names starting with lowercase?

Comment: Yes exacltly, I want to extract the part after the hyphen '-' exlcuding the space the spaces before and after the '-' and the number. I want just the string.

Comment: All the names start with Capital letter.

Comment: did you try replacing your 3 fscanf by the one I put in my solution?